# Rotate Control at Center Point in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

This is my Grid

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform Angle="-180" />
    </Grid.RenderTransform>
</Grid>
```

However, it will be in the wrong position (I want it to rotate on the center point). Hence I need to do something like this:

```
<Grid.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding ???}" CenterY="{Binding ???}" Angle="-180" />
</Grid.RenderTransform>
```

I'm not sure how to do the binding here (calculating the Grid's width/2 and height/2). Can someone give a hand? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try set [`RenderTransformOrigin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for `Grid`:

```
<Grid RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" ... />
```

Quote from [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> `RenderTransformOrigin:` Gets or sets the center point of any possible render transform declared by *`RenderTransform`*, relative to the bounds of the element.